# $state.current.name and $state.current in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the following run block:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $ionicLoading,$location,$localStorage,$state, $timeout,
  $window) {
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
       if($localStorage.userInfo !== null && toState.name !== 'Deployment' &&  $state.current.name !== 'Deployment'){
        $state.go('Deployment', {}, {reload: true});
        console.log($state);
        console.log($state.current);
        event.preventDefault();

         return;
       }

          });
```

**With** `$state`, 
It gives:

```
$current: extend
current: Object
name: "Deployment"
templateUrl: "templates/deployment.html"
url: "/deployment"
__proto__: Object
```

**WITH** $state.current:

```
Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}
```

1. It gives an error that says 10 digest iterations reached. I am skeptical that it's happening because `$state.current.name` is empty and hence if condition failing.
  2.

or may be it is because I am changing state inside of statechangeStart event and it goes into a loop.

How do I fix this error?

Besides why do I get an empty object in $state.current when $state has current object with right values.